# Indexing JSON column in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, mysql-8.0

So I'm experimenting with json column. Mysql 8.0.17 supposed to work with multi value JSON indexes, like this:

`CREATE INDEX data__nbr_idx ON a1( (CAST(data->'$.nbr' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) )`

I have column categories with JSON like this ["books", "clothes"].
I need to get all products from "books" category. I can use "json_contains" or new "member of".

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(categories, '\"books\"')
SELECT * FROM products WHERE "books" MEMBER OF(categories)
```

And it works. The problem is that of course EXPLAIN will reveal that there queries are making full table scan, and because of that it is slow.

So I need some index.

I changed index example by replacing "unsigned" type with "char(32) since my categories are strings and not numbers. I cannot find any example for this in google so I assumed that char() will be fine, but not.

This is my index query:

```
CREATE INDEX categories_index ON products((CAST(categories AS CHAR(32) ARRAY)))
```

also tried

```
CREATE INDEX categories_index ON products((CAST(categories->'$' AS CHAR(32) ARRAY)))
```

but selects are still making full table scan. What I'm doing wrong?
How to correctly index json column without using virtual columns?

Comment: Create generated virtual column with needed expression, then create index by this column. Study [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Secondary Indexes and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html).

Comment: Like I said, I'm trying to do this without virtual columns since new Mysql should have "better" json indexing without this secondary column workaround.

Comment: Index can be created by scalar value only. JSON array is not safe datatype for indexing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a multi-valued json index, the json paths have to match, so with an index

```
CREATE INDEX categories_index 
ON products((CAST(categories->'$' AS CHAR(32) ARRAY)))
```

your query has to also use the path `->'$'` (or the equivalent `json_extract(...,'$')`)

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE "books" MEMBER OF(categories->'$')
```

Make it consistent and it should work.

It seems though that an index without an explicit path does not work as expected, so you have to specify `->'$'` if you want to use the whole document. This is probably a bug, but could also be an intended behaviour of casting or autocasting to an array. If you specify the path you'll be on the safe side.

Comment: Its inconvenient but it's good news that it is actually possible ;) Index now works like a charm.

Comment: PS You missed single ")" and end of index query