# Indexing an array in a MySQL JSON column with variable length elements

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, indexing

I am trying to index json arrays where the contents are variable length strings and I can't figure out if its possible, let alone scalable.

A very similar question about indexing JSON data using the new multi value index is here: [Indexing JSON column in MySQL 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034231/indexing-json-column-in-mysql-8)

The syntax from that question executes, but using CHAR isn't right for me and ends in an error anyway. After changing names and adjusting the CHAR length for my data:

`ALTER TABLE catalog ADD INDEX idx_30144( (CAST( j_data->>'$."30144"' AS char(250) ARRAY)) );`

I get this error

`1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'catalog'; try to repair it`

Trying this:

`ALTER TABLE catalog ADD INDEX idx_30144( (CAST( j_data->>'$."30144"' AS varchar(250) ARRAY)) );`

Gives this error:

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(250) ARRAY)) )' at line 1`

This is an InnoDB table so obviously the 1034 error isn't accurate. It completes in around 2 seconds so while it *could* be running out of space, it happens too fast to see that, and there's 350 GB free on the drive.

I have over 200 JSON nodes like this that I would like to index, ideally. If this is a huge storage suck I can be happy with a subset of them, but I need to know if its possible in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can only index such values, by generating a column which you index

Like

```
CREATE TABLE jempn (
  id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  j_data JSON DEFAULT NULL,
  g varchar(250) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (j_data->'$."30144"' ) STORED,
  INDEX idx_30144 (g)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: The generated column is just the array of strings, but attempting to create an index on it throws the error "1071 - Specified key was too long: max key length is 3072 bytes", likely because some of these arrays are quite long. And wouldn't the index need to be the mutli-value functional kind, still, for json queries to work on it?

Comment: Considering how an index works 250 characters is huge i have only done uuids with 50.an index try to sort the values so that it can quick find the wanted data in a logarithmic number of steps. thinking about it you could generate a FULLTEXT and searching in it with match instead of using an index on 250 characters.